# Netbeans/C++ add environment variable at make

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide

I need to set a variable that is checked in the makefile(i.e. at compile time), but I can't find it in the project properties.

I right-click on the project, but can't find a place to set environment vars, except in the `Run` but even there it seems I can't add a variable (nothing happens when I click on `Add` after expanding the `...`).

What am I missing?

[image]

As a side: Netbeans probably will run a shell before issuing the commands like `make`, what kind of shell is it? how can I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your screenshot that you are on OSX, you should be able to set an environment variable by replacing `"${OUTPUT_PATH}"` under `Run Directory` with `FOO=BAR;"${OUTPUT_PATH}"`. This is normal POSIX syntax for running a program with a specific environment variable or set of variables set, and can be used at the terminal as well.

Edit: In Netbeans, to set an environment variable for a specific action, right click on project, go to Properties->Actions->{Action}->Set Properties: `Add Env.FOO=BAR`.

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't work, I need to set a variable **before** running make